# wechat access token: error 40066

Tags: wechat

Accordingly to [docs](https://mp.weixin.qq.com/wiki?t=resource/res_main&id=mp1421140183), all I have to do after creating dev account, is following:

GET https://api.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/token/?grant_type=client_credential&appid=MY_ID&secret=MY_SECRET

But, I get this:

```
{
  "errcode": 40066,
  "errmsg": "invalid url hint: [qQ0550418k466!]"
}
```

Tried both "api.weixin.qq.com" and "api.wechat.com" domains, no difference.
This error code is not even described in docs.
Does anybody know what to do with this?

Comment: How did you creare Dev account , can you please share? , in official account creation did we have to fill the company registration details and everthing ?? I am freelancer and i dont have any company , can you please guide ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it appears that there should not be slash before "?". That's all.